# RDLC shows duplicates records on the scorelist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rdlc

I was making an rdlc report with groupings. I'm trying to do this.

```
Task          Score
Task 1        5
Task 2        4
Task 3        3
Task 4        2
              1
```

but instead when I ran the program it shows like this

```
Task          Score
Task 1        5
              4
              3
              2
              1

Task 2        5
              4
              3
              2
              1

Task 3        5
              4
              3
              2
              1

Task 4        5
              4
              3
              2
              1
```

=======================================================================

On my dataset I had this as my query

```
Select * from tblTasks
JOIN scores on tblTasks on scores.code = tblTasks.ScoreCode
where date = @date
```

Comment: Without the query generating this report, you won't be able to receive any help.

Comment: My bad sir, This is my query on my dataset. "Select * from tblTasks
JOIN scores on tblTasks on scores.code = tblTasks.ScoreCode
where date = @date"